# Video Sync Down

Tags: google-plus, google-mirror-api, google-glass

Has anyone been seeing issues with the video sync service for Glass being down this weekend?

Specifically, videos I take aren't being synced to G+ and by extension my callback endpoints aren't being notified when when a share of video to a contact happens.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an API's performance at a particular point in time

Comment: Possibly off topic, but it is regarding the mirror api functionality and being that this is the only community currently for Glass developers and Google doesn't have an "API Health" for the sub parts of Glass it doesn't seem like too far of a reach.

Comment: This was tracked on the API issue tracker: https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/detail?id=222  It's marked as fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup I have been having issues specifically related to video:

- Notifications for timeline attachments that are video aren't coming in
- Sharing video onto G+ isn't working (doing it through glass)
- AutoBackup for G+ videos isn't working

Comment: Thanks ozfarman, I've got an email into Google right now and they are looking into it.

Comment: Just FYI, I've got notifications coming in now.

Comment: Indeed, I got an email from one of the guys at Google about an hour ago and everything is working.